# SQL Help Needed

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery, except

Below is a simplified version of my table.

```
    FRID, RELFRID, Relationship
    123, 456, Husband/Wife
    456, 123, Wife/Husband
    345, 765, Brother/Sister
    765, 345, Sister/Brother
```

I want to pull only one representation of the relationship (just one of each set of two records).  I have tried a number of things including EXCEPT and SUBSELECTS and everything I try results in nothing because every number on the left is also represented on the right.  Any idea how to get the results I'm looking for?  I've tried every combination of the queries below.

```
    select frid, relfrid from frrelmst
    except
    select frid, relfrid from frrelmst
    where frid in (select relfrid from frrelmst)
    order by frid, relfrid

    Select frid, relfrid from frrelmst where 
    relfrid+frid not in (select frid+relfrid from frrelmst)
```

Answer (score 7):

Easy :

```
select frid, relfrid from frrelmst where  frid < relfrid
```

Comment: Good but what happens if the record `123, 456, Husband/Wife` doesn't exist?  Or will there always be both representations of a relationship?

Comment: @acatt . . . The question explicitly says "just one of each set of two records", so that it not an issue in this case.  The solution is not generalizable, though.

Comment: @acatt: As Gordon points, thi is not the case. If it was, the condition would have to be altered to something like `... FROM frrelmst  a WHERE frid < relfrid OR frid > relfrid AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM frrelmst b WHERE b.frid = a.relfrid AND b.relfrid = a.frid)`

Comment: I'm going to save this example as well for future reference!!  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'd use the below SQL.  If only one representation of the relationship exists in the table it will still be returned.

```
SELECT frid, relfrid, relationship
FROM frrelmst f
WHERE frid < relfrid
  OR NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM frrelmst
    WHERE frid = f.relfrid
      AND relfrid = f.frid
      AND frid <= f.frid
  )
```